# Return list index of matching elements in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array and it looks like this: `[7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1]`. As you can see there are three elements in this array with the integer value of 2. I want to take this array and create an index that will look something like this: `{ 1 => 1, 2 => 3, 3 => 1, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 1 }`

So, basically a bar chart/histogram/index of a how many duplicates there are in the array.

Just for a high level view of this. I'm trying to find all of the unique emails for each account within my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1]    
1.upto(a.max).each_with_object({}) {|number, hash| hash[number] = a.count(number)}
#=> {1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>1}
```

Comment: Calling `count` for each element of an array or enumerator should sound a warning bell (perhaps accompanied by the flashing message, "Inefficient! Ugly!"). Two alternatives that require only a single pass through the array are always available: construct a counting hash (`Hash.new(0)`) or use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Comment: @CarySwoveland as usually, good point, I thought of `group_by` from the beginning, but it didn't perfectly fit the OP's needs..

Comment: @Bitwise see Cary's answer for more efficient way of achieving the expected reslult

Comment: @EricDuminil I can't tell, since I have no idea what OP's trying to achieve ultimately. Being able to correctly word the question is essential in terms of getting the appropriate help. I showed the OP how to achieve exactly the result he has put as the desired one.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: I agree the question is a bit confusing. The "real" question is in the last sentence IMHO (get unique email addresses), the middle question with example is just a way the OP thinks he can solve the last question.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

This variant should be much faster than the other answers and will work for any array :

```
def histogram(array)
  array.each_with_object( Hash.new(0) ){|number, count| count[number] += 1 }
end

array = [7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b']

p freq = histogram(array)
#=> {7=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 1=>1, "a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}

p array.select{|number| freq[number] == 1}
#=> [7, 3, 1, "a", "c"]
```

## Notes

#### element => 0

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need the `4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0` part in your Hash if all you want to do is to find elements that only appear once.

The information is here if you want to get it, though :

```
p freq[6]
#=> 0
```

#### SQL ?

If your array comes from a database via ActiveRecord, it might be a better idea to find the unique elements directly with a SQL query instead of retrieving all elements and applying logic to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [8, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2]

min, max = arr.minmax
  #=> [2, 8] 
arr.each_with_object((min..max).to_a.product([0]).to_h) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {2=>1, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>1}
```

Note:

```
(min..max).to_a.product([0]).to_h
  #=> {2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0}
```

Comment: Note that the "real" question is about email addresses. For `['a@a.com', 'z@z.com']`, your method creates 11863801 arrays!